# Dissolving closest area or area with biggest shared boarder

Tags: arcpy, dissolve, redistricting

I am almost finished with a very large districting project but I'm having problems with this last step.

I am using ArcMap

I have made districts that needs to be larger than 150 residents. My last code has finished it all but I still have a few areas that does not quite hit the required goal. What I want to do, is to dissolve these few areas that are too small with either the area that is shares the biggest boarder with or the closest area if it is not connected directly. I have made a new field called "areasmall" that I coded 0 for correct size (larger than 150) and 1 for too small (smaller than 150). I need a way to automate the dissolve process so that areas that have 1 in areasmall are dissolved into an area with 0 in areasmall and sums up the resident count in the "residents"-field. I work with python, so code would be great! I have included a picture where the red areas are the big ones and the yellow are the small ones.

[image: Areas]

Comment: Have you looked at the eliminate tool?

Comment: I think you will need to use ArcPy to meet your requirements so for help with that we'll need you to include a code snippet that shows what you have tried and where you are stuck.